# Como mostrar dados da data mais recente?

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela1:

- ID Auto_Increment;
- nome varchar;
- data date;

Gostaria que aparece-se apenas os dados com a data mais recente. Como faço?

Comment: todas as linha que tiverem a data mais recente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE data = (SELECT data FROM tabela1 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer isso tudo em um único select:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1
```