# Como montar um SELECT para retornar a ultima alteração de status de cada id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

status_faturas

```
id_fatura | status | data
----------------------------------------
XX-XX-XX  |   3    | 2017-01-04 21:00:24
XX-XX-XX  |   2    | 2017-01-02 11:10:20
YY-YY-YY  |   4    | 2017-01-04 21:00:24
YY-YY-YY  |   1    | 2017-01-02 11:10:20
----------------------------------------
```

Como posso montar uma consulta para me retornar (id_fatura, status,data) da ultima alteração de status?

O resultado da consulta deve ser algo como:

```
id_fatura | status | data
----------------------------------------
XX-XX-XX  |   3    | 2017-01-04 21:00:24
YY-YY-YY  |   4    | 2017-01-04 21:00:24
----------------------------------------
```

Como fazer isso em uma consulta SQL?
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Essa é legal, de DB pra DB tem truques diferentes para conseguir isto. No SQLite, em versões recentes, bastaria um `MAX()` na coluna `data` para forçar a coluna `status` acompanhar (e isso é um recurso documentado). No MySQL o `ORDER BY ... DESC` funciona, mas não há promessa de ser sempre assim em versoes futuras.

Comment: Então... tentei de maneiras que acharia que daria certo, mas acontecia que o status não acompanhava. Excelente truque kk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um jeito simples seria fazer isto:

```
SELECT
  `id_fatura`, `status`, `data`
FROM
  `status_faturas`
GROUP BY
  `id_fatura`
ORDER BY
  `data` DESC
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95c86f/1)**.

neste caso o `ORDER BY data DESC` faz com que o grupo retorne sempre o de data maior.

O problema é:

- É um comportamento não portátil, específico do MySQL
- O próprio manual diz que isso pode mudar um dia, em alguma versão mais nova, em favor de uma otimização melhor de agrupamento.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

### Alternativa segura e portátil:

Com um pouco de "artimanha" dá pra fazer algo um pouco diferente:

```
SELECT
   A.id_fatura,
   A.status,
   A.data
FROM
   status_faturas A
LEFT JOIN
   status_faturas B
   ON  A.id_fatura = B.id_fatura
   AND B.data > A.data
WHERE
   B.id_fatura IS NULL
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/908b81/1)**.

Isto funciona da seguinte forma:

- Primeiro, relacionamos a tabela duas vezes, sendo que do lado direito só serão retornadas de fato as linhas com o campo `data` de valor maior que o da esquerda, para cada `id_fatura`;
- Como usamos `LEFT JOIN`, todas as colunas da esquerda serão retornadas ao menos uma vez, mesmo não conseguindo satisfazer a cláusula `ON`;

  Entenda o motivo neste post:

  > [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)
- E aí vem o truque: com o `WHERE` nós descartamos todas as que tem uma data maior, e o que sobra é só a mais nova de cada grupo, que é o nosso objetivo final

**Nota 1:** no exemplo acima usei o `data` que foi posto na pergunta, mas se tem duas datas iguais, o resultado é imprevisível (seja qual for o método utilizado). Melhor seria, caso esteja lançando tudo na sequência temporal correta, usar `B.id > A.id`, sendo `id` a coluna de autonumeração da sua tabela.

**Nota 2:** O approach mais comum é uma combinação de SELECT e JOIN com MAX, que pode ser visto nesta postagem - mas é importante notar que o MAX nesse caso provavelmente não vai aproveitar índices:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151096/70

Comment: Perfeito @Bacco :)