# Select de todos usuários com somente um resultado de cada usuário

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, select, while

Olá, boa noite.
Acho que o título está um pouco confuso, vou tenta explica melhor.

Estou fazendo um sistema de chat e estou querendo listar todas as conversas dos usuários, mas somente uma mensagem de cada usuário.

Exemplo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Está mostrando todas as mensagens do usuário Mateus, mas queria mostrar somente uma.

Meu BD:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu select

```
SELECT * FROM pw_chat ORDER BY data ASC
```

Comment: Se quer a mais recente, melhor especificar na pergunta. A resposta atual dada abaixo pega uma de cada, mas não garante que seja a mais nova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito simples, basta agrupar pelo usuário:

```
SELECT * FROM pw_chat GROUP BY usuario ORDER BY data DESC
```

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bbfe2/1)

Comment: Amigo formate o seu código para facilitar a leitura do mesmo. [Saiba mais sobre formatação…](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Só acho que deveria ser DESC. já que ele quer a última postagem

Comment: Deveria trocar o ASC por DESC

Comment: Mais uma experiencia adquirida, muito obrigado. a todos :D

Comment: CUIDADO: Isto **não garante a mais recente**. Depende do DB. As funções de agrupamento não respeitam necessariamente o ORDER. O ORDER é aplicado depois do agrupamento em muitos engines. O SQLite, por exemplo, deixa claro que só garante se você usar um MAX( id ) ou coisa do tipo. O MySQL avisa no manual que isso é um efeito colateral e pode mudar a qualquer momento.

Comment: Mais ou menos o que está explicado aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175280/